# Flyway Migrations fails when passing Environment Variables to Docker

Tags: mysql, docker, environment-variables, flyway

Performing database migrations using `flyway`. Using the dockerized version and using `conf` files for mirgations configurations.

Below is my config file

```
flyway.url = jdbc:mysql://${MYSQLHOST}:3306/myschema
flyway.user = myusername
flyway.password = mypassword
flyway.schemas = myschema
flyway.cleanDisabled = true
```

Am running the below command to perform migration

```
sudo docker run -e "MYSQLHOST=myhostip" --rm -it -v `pwd`/path/to/confi/:/flyway/conf/ -v `pwd`/path/to/migrations:/flyway/sql boxfuse/flyway:5.1.4 -configFiles=/flyway/conf/flyway.conf migrate
```

Am getting the below error

```
ERROR: 
Unable to obtain connection from database (jdbc:mysql://${MYSQLHOST}:3306/myschema) for user 'myuser': Could not connect to address=(host=${MYSQLHOST})(port=3306)(type=master) : ${MYSQLHOST}
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SQL State  : 08
Error Code : -1
Message    : Could not connect to address=(host=${MYSQLHOST})(port=3306)(type=master) : ${MYSQLHOST}
```

If I change the config file with my host ip details the migrations are successful without any errors. What am I doing wrongly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flyway allows you to pass in configuration parameters via a specific set of environment variables; it doesn't perform a complete variable substitution in the config file. See https://flywaydb.org/documentation/envvars.

What you could do is delete the first line of the config file, then

`sudo docker run -e "FLYWAY_URL=jdbc:mysql://myhostip:3306/myschema" ...`

Comment: Am I missing something here? Aren't we not breaking the usage of configuration file then

Comment: Passing the URL by config file, environment variable, and command line option are all equivalent. In what way would you be breaking the conf file?

Comment: environment variables are supported now, see https://flywaydb.org/documentation/configuration/configfile#environment-variable-substitution

Answer (score 0):

I found it not very helpful to only see a page explaining that there are envVars -- but no mention of the exact env variable names to actually use.

Here is the definition of the env names / especially for the gradle plugin but I suspect that they are generally valid:

https://github.com/flyway/flyway/blob/master/flyway-core/src/main/java/org/flywaydb/core/internal/configuration/ConfigUtils.java#L139